# grounding a 220 -> 110 V transformer

Tags: transformer, grounding

I'm in Brazil and
my house has 220V power.
I have a transformer that converts 220 to 110V
It has 2 prong power in
and 2 prong power out.

I would like to make the output grounded. I'm hooking up things with 3 prong connectors and I prefer not to simply "bypass ground" with adapters

Can I simply connect the ground prong to the transformer chassis or is there a better way?

Comment: this has me worried
  http://www.gson.org/stepdown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure of your input wires, i.e. which is live and which is neutral, you should tie one of the output prongs of the transformer to neutral, and your three prong connector will then receive the house ground in the middle, and the two transformer output prongs in the other two connectors.

Grounding the transformer chassis is also a very good idea.

Please note that this solution is better than connecting to ground one of the transformer output because your RCD will keep working, i.e. if you touch one of the transformer output prongs and drive some current to ground your RCD can detect that since this current is forced to come from the N wire. If you hook one output prong to ground and touch the other you can get some serious trouble.

If you want to achieve full output isolation (I don't think so) then don't connect either prong to ground or whatever, but you better put an RCD on the transformer output to protect the end user.

If you just want to power some 110VAC rated device just stick with the first solution and you'll be safe.

**addendum**

Here is the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVGlXq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: i have *three* input wires, the *transformer* only accepts 2

Comment: Adding a schematic for you, I knew I should draw it from the beginning. Hold tight @CharlesSpencer

Comment: thanks Vlad! i ended up doing something different
my 110V device is a "Monster Power Pro7000" and it has a external ground connect.. I connected that to house ground and left the connection from the transformer to the Monster Power 2 prong.  I'm only seeing electricity leaking from the transformer now, everything else is clean. (i'm using a screwdriver that has an electricity detecting light)

Comment: I'd love to see a schematic of what you have done. If you poked around with a [test light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_light) you should be safe but you know... better safer than sorry. @CharlesSpencer